# Sending POST request with GET parameter in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, get, routes

For example, I have this route in my web.php :-

```
Route::get('products/{product}/owners', 'ProductController@showOwners');
```

When I try to add new 'Owner' to the product, I have to do it in the parent URL, like this :-

```
Route::post('products/storeOwner', 'ProductController@storeOwner');
```

And then I pass the product ID in a hidden field in the form, because the post request doesn't accept URL parameters. So is there anyway to do it like below ?

```
Route::post('products/{product}/storeOwner', 'ProductController@storeOwner');
```

So the POST request will be sent inside the particular 'product' URL?

**UPDATE**

```
/* ProductController Class */
public function storeOwner (AddProductOwner $request)
    {

        $product= Product::find($request->product);
        $user = Auth::user();

        if ( $user->ownerOf($product)) {
            // Check if the current user is already one of the owners).
            // If the current user is the owner then return to the product
            // This line is not executed because in (products/show.blade.php) we have set a condition.

            return redirect('products/' . $request->product);
        }

        $join = new Join;
        $join->role = $request->join_role;
        $join->product()->associate($request->product);
        $join->user()->associate(Auth::user());

        $join->message = $request->message;


        $join->save();

        // TODO: we have to make this with ajax instead of normal form
        return redirect('products/'. $request->product);
}
```

I hope my question is clear enough..

Comment: Sure. That will work if the route and URL are defined correctly.

Comment: POST request doesn't accept parameters in the URL

Comment: I've been using it like the two answers below. Laravel is smart that way. It's technically not POST, it's URL parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do as you mentioned in your last route

```
Route::post('products/{product}/storeOwner', 'ProductController@storeOwner');
```

And then get the product Id in your functions argument

```
public function storeOwner (AddProductOwner $request, $productId)
{
    dd($productId);    // TRY THIS OUT. CHECK THE 2nd ARGUMENT I SET.
    $product= Product::find($productId);    // PASS THE VERIABLE HERE.
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ( $user->ownerOf($product)) {
        // Check if the current user is already one of the owners).
        // If the current user is the owner then return to the product
        // This line is not executed because in (products/show.blade.php) we have set a condition.

        return redirect('products/' . $request->product);
    }

    $join = new Join;
    $join->role = $request->join_role;
    $join->product()->associate($request->product);
    $join->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    $join->message = $request->message;


    $join->save();

    // TODO: we have to make this with ajax instead of normal form
    return redirect('products/'. $request->product);
```

}

Comment: I tried this method, POST request doesn't allow to send URL parameter

Comment: Can you post the function `storeOwner` in your question?

Comment: Update the questions, Thanks

Comment: @HamedAdil, Updated my answer accordingly. Give it a try.

Comment: @HamedAdil, notice first two lines of the function in my answer and the 2nd argument I passed.

Comment: Perfect!, It worked like charm after a little dive in the code, Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You can send URL parameters to a POST request. Just make sure in your form you are sending the wildcard.

```
 <form action="/products/{{ $productid }}/storeOwner" method="POST">
```

In your routes

```
Route::post('products/{productid}/storeOwner', 'ProductController@storeOwner');
```

In your controller, use it

```
public function storeOwner($productid)
{
    dd($productid);
}
```